# Including ecto migrations or generators in a hex package

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, elixir-mix

I need to publish a simple Elixir library/hex package that adds a table to it's parent app's database. Should I create a migration that is copied into the parent app or should I look at creating a generator?

Comment: It's a bit hard to decipher what you're asking but I believe I'd be thinking about using shell scripts to accomplish this.

Comment: I'm working within a mix task using Elixir. I need to access the package contents with File.cp

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you're even asking for.  Try to make your question a bit clearer and you may get some help.

Comment: Even if this was possible, I can't imagine a scenario where I would want a package I was depending on to do this.

Comment: What is odd about a package that requires a database table to be added? This is fairly common in practice in ruby using bundler/rake/migrations etc right?

Comment: @errata I haven't worked with ruby much, so I wouldn't know. I'm not used to packages that are impacting the database that way, so it just seems strange to me. I guess the example in the answer of GuardianDb is all I would expect. Now this gives me something to think about.

Answer (score 4):

I think that a mix task that generates the migration would be the correct way to do it.

```
$ mix package.install
```

Also there are a couple of projects that ask the user to manually add the migration like GuardianDb.

https://github.com/hassox/guardian_db

Comment: I guess the mix task is probably the best way to go if I need to add several migrations.